# CSS acting very strangely, specifically with spacing

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm making a page with a registration form for new users to my ASP.NET site to create accounts. I've copied a responsive horizontal CSS form template from the following URL: https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/responsive-css3-form-fields-tutorial. The page on my site that utilizes this form is https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net/Registration. If you look at it, you clearly see some styling issues. First, I'll show you the important parts of the HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form runat="server" onsubmit="return false">
<h1>Personal Information</h1>
<span style="float: right; font-size: 1.5em"><span class="red">*</span>&nbsp;Required</span>
<div class="col-4">
<label>
  Date of Birth (DOB) <span class="red">*</span>
<input type="date" required="required" placeholder="When is your date of birth?" id="dob" name="dob" tabindex="10" />
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
  <label>
    Gender <span class="red">*</span>
    <select id="gender" required="required" name="gender" tabindex="11">
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
      <option>I do not wish to identify</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-4 switch">
  <label>Send Text Notifications?</label>
  <center style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 8px"><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" /></center>
</div>
<div class="col-4 switch">
  <label>Email Updates?</label>
  <center style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 8px"><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" /></center>
</div>
<div id="BottomSection">
<br />
<h1 style="background-color: blueviolet">Login Information</h1>
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em">
    Enter password hint for future reference:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />I have read and agree to the <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/PrivacyPolicy.html">Privacy Policy</asp:HyperLink> &nbsp;and <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/TermsOfService.html">Terms Of Service</asp:HyperLink>.</div>
<div class="col-submit">
<button class="submitbtn">Submit Form</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
form > div.switch > label {
   padding: 22px 20px 18px;
}

label > input {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 27px;
   line-height: 27px;
   margin: 5px -5px 0;
   padding: 7px 5px 3px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: #555;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
   opacity: .6;
   transition: all linear .3s;
}

label > select {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 7px 5px 3px;
   margin: 5px -5px 0;
   color: #555;
   font-weight: 500;
   height: 35px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   opacity: .6;
   transition: all linear .3s;
}
```

As you can see, I have tweaked some of the code provided from the original source, but that is only code I've fixed for the better, as it looks differently on my end. For the full CSS stylesheet, go to https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net/Style/styles.css. Here are my issues:

1) No `h1` headings or even just regular HTML text - like the text saying an asterisk (*) means the field is required and the text next to the ASP.NET checkbox - are showing up, despite showing up on Visual Studio's design file.

2) For the bottom row, there are clearly some issues with the spacing and borders. The blue border appears, but it is thicker than the blue border on above rows and there is also some whitespace to go along with it, and an uneven height and padding for each each column on the bottom row. I've tried tweaking and experimenting with many different `padding` and `margin` values, but it keeps remaining uneven. Lastly, I also did a line break (`<br>`) to give some space between the form fields and the ASP.NET CreateUserWizard control, but it also isn't being applied.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Max. This question is way too big. I suggest you pair it down to something really simple - because / just figuring out what your question is - is going to take a while. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and maybe make a really small example of the exact problems in a https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @sheriffderek - Thanks for your feedback, I just condensed my question down to as small as possible while keeping the needed information.

Comment: I meant really really simple. What is the question? Your CSS isn't "acting strange" - its just not written well / and it's doing exactly whatever it says to do. It's a set of declared rules. If you actually want to learn this stuff / then I suggest you break it down much much further.

Comment: @sheriffderek - Sorry, sometimes there's just a lot of information needed to figure out a problem. My questions came from the 2 issues I listed at the bottom of my question. But I do agree that my CSS wasn't acting strange and instead was performing as it should have - it just seemed odd at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove `font-size: 0` from the `form` selector in order to see the headings.

```
form {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #7eaf4a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 0;         /* <- remove this */
}
```

2) Update the `.col-3, .col-4` selector with a `vertical-align: top` and a `min-height` in order to have them all with the same height and style.

```
.col-3, .col-4 { 
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0026ff;
  border-right: 3px solid #0026ff;
  background-color: #ebf442;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

I've updated a bit the `<span>Required</span>` element, and the media queries in order to have the responsive design working, with the fixes mentioned above included.
Snippet below:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Laila:400,700);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion|Muli:400,600');

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html { overflow-y: scroll; }

body {
  font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background: #e2eef4;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.red { color: red }

input, textarea { 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  outline: none; 
}

strong, b { font-weight: bold; }
em, i { font-style: italic; }

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3.1em;
  line-height: 1.45em;
  font-family: 'Laila', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  background-color: #ebf442;
}

/** form field **/
form {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #7eaf4a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* font-size: 0; */
}

form > div > label {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #939393;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form > div.switch > label {
  padding: 22px 20px 18px;
}

.col-3, .col-4 { 
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0026ff !important;
  border-right: 3px solid #0026ff !important;
  background-color: #ebf442;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.col-4 {
  float: left;
}

label > input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin: 5px -5px 0;
  padding: 7px 5px 3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: .6;
  transition: all linear .3s;
}

label > select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 5px 3px;
    margin: 5px -5px 0;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: .6;
    transition: all linear .3s;
}

.col-submit {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

label > input:focus, label > select:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

/** button design based on http://codepen.io/guvootes/pen/eyDAb **/
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}

button.submitbtn {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#97c16b, #8ab959);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#97c16b, #8ab959);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#97c16b, #8ab959);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #648c3a;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
button.submitbtn:hover {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#8ab959, #7eaf4a);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#8ab959, #7eaf4a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8ab959, #7eaf4a);
}
button.submitbtn:active {
  height: 34px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#7eaf4a, #8ab959);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7eaf4a, #8ab959);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#7eaf4a, #8ab959);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#BottomSection {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    display: block;
}

/** responsive design **/

@media(min-width: 150px) {
    form > div {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .col-submit {
        display: block;
    }

    .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px #0026ff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #0026ff;
        border-right: 1px solid #0026ff;
    }

    .col-2 {
        width: 50%
    }

    .col-3 {
        width: 33.3333333333%
    }

    .col-4 {
        width: 25%
    }

    .col-submit button {
        width: 30%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
    #app_body {
        padding-left: 0 !important
    }

    #main_fields div.field label, #eeoc_fields div.field label {
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        text-align: left !important;
        display: block !important
    }

    #main_fields .field-error-msg {
        padding-left: 0 !important
    }

    #education_section .select2-container, #custom_fields .select2-container, #custom_fields div.field input[type=text], #custom_fields div.field textarea, #custom_fields div.field select, #main_fields div.field input[type=text], #main_fields div.field textarea, #eeoc_fields div.field input[type=text], #eeoc_fields div.field textarea {
        width: 100% !important;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box
    }

    #eeoc_fields div.field select, #custom_fields div.field select {
        width: 100% !important
    }

    .accessible #header {
        padding-right: 0
    }

    .accessible #resume_paste, .accessible #cover_letter_paste {
        margin-left: 0 !important
    }

    .accessible div.required-fields {
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
        right: 30px;
        top: 30px
    }

    .accessible #custom_fields .field label:not(:first-child) {
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: inline-block
    }

    .accessible #main_fields div.field textarea.paste, .accessible #eeoc_fields div.field textarea.paste {
        margin-left: 0
    }

    .accessible #main_fields .employment .field input[type='checkbox'] {
        margin-left: 0 !important
    }

    .accessible #main_fields .employment .field label.current {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: auto !important
    }

    .accessible .filter-container select {
        width: 100% !important
    }

    .accessible .locate-me, .accessible .year {
        margin-top: 10px !important
    }

    .accessible #add_education, .accessible #add_employment {
        margin: 0 !important
    }

    .accessible .remove-background-field {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        top: -15px;
        right: 0
    }
  
  .col-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<form runat="server" onsubmit="return false">
  
<h1>Personal Information</h1>
  
<span style="font-size: 1.5em; position: absolute; z-index: 1; right: 40px;">
  <span class="red">*</span>
  <span>&nbsp;Required</span>
</span>

  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Date of Birth (DOB) <span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="date" required="required" placeholder="When is your date of birth?" id="dob" name="dob" tabindex="10" />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Gender <span class="red">*</span>
      <select id="gender" required="required" name="gender" tabindex="11">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>I do not wish to identify</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 switch">
    <label>Send Text Notifications?</label>
    <center style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 8px"><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" /></center>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 switch">
    <label>Email Updates?</label>
    <center style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 8px"><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" /></center>
  </div>

  
<div id="BottomSection">
<br />
  
<h1 style="background-color: blueviolet">Login Information</h1>
  
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em">
    Enter password hint for future reference:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />I have read and agree to the <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/PrivacyPolicy.html">Privacy Policy</asp:HyperLink> &nbsp;and <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/TermsOfService.html">Terms Of Service</asp:HyperLink>.</div>
<div class="col-submit">
<button class="submitbtn">Submit Form</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: And if you want to have a thinner blue border, update the `3px` value from the `border-right` and `border-bottom`, on the `.col-3, .col-4` selector.

Comment: Andrei - thanks a lot for your detailed answer, I can see you put a lot of time and effort into it. I should have paid more attention to figure out issue #1 with the `font` set to 0 - that was easy. HOWEVER, once I did that, it somehow threw the horizontal spacing of the form fields off so that the width didn't stretch across the entire page, so I changed the `font-size` of the headings and text with some inner HTML. As for issue #2, that worked to perfection. Thanks again!